# Problem with UUID, program throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Please don't mark it as a duplicate, I tried following answers to other questions but it didn't help.

I have a problem with an app that I made in intellij according to a tutorial provided by my professor (yes I asked for help, he was not able to help me). I did everything according to the tutorial (or I think so) but when I try to run the application a get this message in my Logcat:

```
2020-11-30 17:50:05.577 9262-9262/com.example.todoapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.todoapp, PID: 9262
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.todoapp.Task.getName()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.todoapp.TaskFragment.onCreateView(TaskFragment.java:54)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I understand from this massage that there is a problem with Task().getName but I don't know why would it be null. Here are my activities: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.todoapp;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        UUID taskId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(TaskListFragment.KEY_EXTRA_TASK_ID);
        return TaskFragment.newInstance(taskId);
    }
}
```

SingleFragmentActivity.java:

```
package com.example.todoapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
}
```

TaskListActivity.java:

```
package com.example.todoapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class TaskListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment() {
        return new TaskListFragment();
    }
}
```

And here are my classes: Task.java

```
package com.example.todoapp;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Task {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    private boolean done;

    public Task() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
        date = new Date();
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }


    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }
}
```

TaskFragment.java:

```
package com.example.todoapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.util.UUID;

public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText nameField;
    private Button dateButton;
    private CheckBox doneCheckBox;
    private Task task;
    private static final String ARG_TASK_ID = "ARG_TASK_ID";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UUID taskId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_TASK_ID);
        task = TaskStorage.getInstance().getTaskById(taskId);
    }

    public static TaskFragment newInstance(UUID taskId) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(ARG_TASK_ID, taskId);
        TaskFragment taskFragment = new TaskFragment();
        taskFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return taskFragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);
        nameField = view.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
        dateButton = view.findViewById(R.id.task_date);
        doneCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.task_done);

        nameField.setText(task.getName());

        nameField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                task.setName(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        dateButton.setText(task.getDate().toString());
        dateButton.setEnabled(false);

        doneCheckBox.setChecked(task.isDone());
        doneCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                task.setDone(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return view;

    }



}
```

TaskLIstFragment.java:

```
package com.example.todoapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class TaskListFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String KEY_EXTRA_TASK_ID = "KEY_EXTRA_TASK_ID";
    private TaskAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private void updateView() {
        TaskStorage taskStorage = TaskStorage.getInstance();
        List<Task> tasks = taskStorage.getTaskList();

        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new TaskAdapter(tasks);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateView();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.task_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateView();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView nameTextView;
        private TextView dateTextView;
        private Task task;
        private final LinearLayout itemElement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_element);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_TASK_ID, task.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void bind(final Task task) {
            this.task = task;
            itemElement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_TASK_ID, task.getId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            nameTextView.setText(task.getName());
            dateTextView.setText(task.getDate().toString());
        }

        public TaskHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, parent, false));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_name);
            dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_date);
        }
    }

    private class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskHolder> {

        private List<Task> tasks;

        public TaskAdapter(List<Task> tasks) {
            this.tasks = tasks;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            return new TaskHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TaskHolder holder, int position) {
            Task task = tasks.get(position);
            holder.bind(task);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return tasks.size();
        }
    }
}
```

TaskStorage.java:

```
package com.example.todoapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class TaskStorage {
    private static final TaskStorage ourInstance = new TaskStorage();

    public static TaskStorage getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private List<Task> taskList;

    private TaskStorage() {
        taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            Task tmp = new Task();
            tmp.setName("Task nr " + i);
            taskList.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    public List<Task> getTaskList() {
        return taskList;
    }

    public Task getTaskById(UUID id) {
        for(Task task:taskList) {
            if(task.getId().equals(id)) return task;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

I think that the problem is with the UUID. It comes out null by I don't know why. I would greatly appreciate the help as I don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

I tried changing

```
@Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```

to:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    nameField.setText(task.getName());
}
```

I also tried to initialise name in the Task constructor, but the error was still there.

Comment: _"...there is a problem with Task().getName but I don't know why would it be null."_ That's the wrong question. :) Your job is to make it not null before you use it. So, the correct question is "Why would it not be null?". The only reason I see in the code given is `task = TaskStorage.getInstance().getTaskById(taskId);`. So what is this mysterious `TaskStorage` and what makes us assume that there are any tasks with the given `taskId`? Looks like the only place in the code that could put any tasks into it is the constructor: `private TaskStorage() {...}`. I'd focus on that. Does it get called?

Comment: I didn't follow the code carefully, but a random id is given to each task. Is the right id given when trying to find a task? I'd focus on that too.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TaskFragment`:

Either the method `onCreate` is not invoked before `onCreateView` (therefore the instance variable `task` was never assigned) or `TaskStorage.getInstance().getTaskById(taskId);` just returns null, because there is no task for the given id - and you actively returning null in such cases.

I cannot judge about the invocation of lifecycle methods, since I am not into app development, but I guess this is probably something your professor would know.

Therefore I guess there is just no task for the given id.

You can avoid the `NullPointerException` by returning a dummy task, like so:

```
    public Task getTaskById(UUID id) {
        for(Task task:taskList) {
            if(task.getId().equals(id)) return task;
        }
        return new Task();
    }
```

But this will most likely not solve your problem, just pushing it to another place.

I think a cleaner way would be to either throw an exception, when no task can be found, or returning an optional and handle it properly:

```
    public Optional<Task> getTaskById(UUID id) {
        for(Task task:taskList) {
            if(task.getId().equals(id)) return Optional.of(task);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

/// or:
    public Task getTaskById(UUID id) {
        for(Task task:taskList) {
            if(task.getId().equals(id)) return task;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("There is no task for id '%s'", id));
    }
```

I'd personally prefer the Optional-variant since it is clear for method-callers, that there is the possibility of an empty optional being returned.